# Paste text files and add parent directory name as header for each column

Tags: text-processing, files, paste

In a parent folder I have multiple folders inside it. Within each folder I have text file "text.txt". The text files are similar in all the folders, each text file contain 100 line and one column of numbers. example

```
cat /folder1/text1.txt

1654
1684
535
35131
.
.
```

I want to merge all these text files as columns in one file using the command `paste`. In the parent folder I ran the command

```
paste ./*/text*.text > all_text.txt  # the content for all_text.txt is as follow:

cat all_text.txt
1654        354531 ....
1684        224
535         2424 
35131       24
.
.
.
```

How can I add the folders names as a header for each pasted column to get the following output

```
cat all_text.txt
folder#1   folder #2   .....
1654        354531
1684        224
535         2424 
35131       24
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `set` and parameter expansion on each array element to print just the directory name:

```
set -- */text.txt
{ printf '      %s' "${@%/*}" | cut -c2-;  paste -- "$@"; }
# this blank ^ is a literal tab
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your help is highly appreciated :)