# Create header to table from the output of the command "paste"

Tags: text-processing, files, paste

I have folder (data) contain large number of text files. Each text file contain one column of numbers, the column contain 30 numbers. I want to create table that combine the columns in these text files. I used the following command:

```
  cd data
  paste *.txt > all_data.txt
```

The output is as follows:

```
0.834679    0.612341    0.510057    0.580128  .....
1.837894    1.061547    0.961449    1.343096  .....
1.638215    1.024628    1.113596    1.80506  .....
1.596119    0.971842    1.14204     1.73881  .....
1.568142    1.025716    1.217219    1.769668  .....
1.554016    0.977165    1.226769    1.786335  .....
1.543137    1.001812    1.247598    1.840443  .....
1.491823    0.99437     1.28337     1.784271  .....
1.371208    0.931998    1.259749    1.717408  .....
1.390867    0.905996    1.300722    1.739213  .....
1.35813     0.283377    1.307122    1.733058  .....
......
```

This command combined all the columns in one big spreadsheet. My question: is there any way to paste each column in the text files and make the text file name header to that column. As follows:

```
text_file1  text_file2  text_file3  text_file4 ....  
0.834679    0.612341    0.510057    0.580128  .....
1.837894    1.061547    0.961449    1.343096  .....
1.638215    1.024628    1.113596    1.80506  .....
1.596119    0.971842    1.14204     1.73881  .....
1.568142    1.025716    1.217219    1.769668  .....
1.554016    0.977165    1.226769    1.786335  .....
1.543137    1.001812    1.247598    1.840443  .....
1.491823    0.99437     1.28337     1.784271  .....
1.371208    0.931998    1.259749    1.717408  .....
1.390867    0.905996    1.300722    1.739213  .....
1.35813     0.283377    1.307122    1.733058  .....
......
```

Comment: Very similar to _another question of yours_: [Paste text files and add parent directory name as header for each column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322607/22142)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
paste_with_header() (
  IFS=$(printf '\t') # or IFS=$'\t' with some shells
  printf '%s\n' "$*"
  paste -- "$@"
)

paste_with_header text_file* > all_data.txt
```

`"$*"` is expanded to the list of positional parameters (the arguments to the function) joined with the first character of `$IFS`, which we set to `TAB`, the character that `paste` also uses to join lines of the file.

To remove the file extensions in the header, with `zsh`:

```
paste_with_header() (
  printf '%s\n' ${(pj:\t:)@:r}
  paste -- "$@"
)
```

- `${@:r}` expands to the root name (extension removed) of each positional parameter.
- `j:\t:` parameter expansion flag to join on `\t`. With `p` that `\t` is interpreted as a `TAB`

Or with `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash` assuming files do have an extension or that no directory in their path components contain dots:

```
paste_with_header() (
  IFS=$'\t'
  printf '%s\n' "${@%.*}"
  paste -- "$@"
)
```

`${@%.*}` removes the shortest trailing part that matches `.*` off the end of each of the positional parameters (`foo.txt` becomes `foo`, but beware that `./foo` becomes the empty string).

(those obviously assume the file names don't contain tabulations or newline characters).

Comment: Thank you so much for the great input. May I kindly ask if you can provide explanation for learning purposes.

Comment: I tried the last function in bash. There is no output data? I am sure that I am missing something

Comment: @goro, you still need to invoke that function (like with `paste_with_header text_file*.txt > all_data.txt`)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and for the explanations! I hope I can give you more than one thumb up ;-)